# How to use "Use method" to add CORS to my middleware

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, cors, asp.net-authorization

The Startup class of an API project I am working on has something like this:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup("DevelopmentConfig", typeof(Startup.DevelopmentStartup))]
```

and then the `Configuration` method has a signature like this where IAppBuilder is `Owin.IAppBuilder`

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
```

so I want to add a `app.UseCors()` to it but there is no such thing. It only has an appBuilder.Use()  method.
How can I use CORS in here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors by

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors
```

Comment: looks like my API project is .NET 4.5.2 : I got this error for installation: "Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files 
that are compatible with that framework."

Comment: oh It's not .net core. Then go for Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors